# In Mac - fstat will always sets st_mtimespec.tv_sec to 0

Tags: macos

In Mac OS, I have application which reads the file only - when the file is been modified by other application. For this i am using checking file modification time stamp using fstat. Below is the code snyppet

```
  fstat(mHFile,&mCurrentTimeStamp);

  mCurrentTimeStamp.st_mtimespec.tv_sec will gives information up to seconds field DDMMYYY HR:MM:SS

  But mCurrentTimeStamp.st_mtimespec.tv_nsec is always 0. Because of this, if the application has modified below 1 second - I wont be able to read those kind of messages.

  Reading of messages which are modified with in 1 second duration is very important for my application.

  What i have to do for this?
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [File System Events API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)